# PowerShell Get the Friday 12 Months From This Friday

Tags: powershell, date, dayofweek

I'm currently writing a PowerShell script for backup tapes and trying to calculate return dates of the tapes.  Tapes are picked up and returned by our provider on Fridays.  Retention periods are 4 weeks, 12 months and 3 years.  Monthly tapesets fall on the first Monday of the month so I'm currently working with a monthly tapeset, which will return 12 months from now.  How would I calculate 12 months from Friday 10/08/2021, but make sure the return date is also a Friday?

```
#Calculate Friday - Vaulting Date
$Friday = (Get-Date).AddDays(5-((Get-Date).DayOfWeek.value__)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

#Calculate Return Dates
$Weekly = (Get-Date).AddDays(5-((Get-Date).DayOfWeek.value__)).AddDays(28).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
$Monthly = (Get-Date).AddDays(5-((Get-Date).DayOfWeek.value__)).AddMonths(12).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
$Yearly = (Get-Date).AddDays(5-((Get-Date).DayOfWeek.value__)).AddYears(3).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

$Monthly currently returns 10/08/2022 which is the Saturday after the date I want.  I presume I'd run into the same problem with $Yearly as well, and what if it's a leap year?  Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: As an aside: you don't need the `.value__` property in your method calls, because PowerShell _automatically_ converts enumeration values such as `Sunday` (from enumeration [`System.DayOfWeek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DayOfWeek)) to their underlying numbers (integers).

Comment: Another aside: It's best to lock in the starting date with a _single_ `Get-Date` call, whose result is stored in a variable, which can then be used in later calculations. Aside from being more efficient, it also avoids problems - even though largely hypothetical - of unwittingly crossing calendar-day or DST-transition boundaries between `Get-Date` calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track, except:

- Your `$someDate.AddDays(5-($someDate.DayOfWeek))` method of finding the Friday that falls into the same week as `$someDate` must be applied *after* the `.AddMonths()`, ... calls, i.e. to the *results* of the future-date-by-offset values.

  - Note: Due to basing your calculation on the [`System.DayOfWeek`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DayOfWeek) enumeration, which ranges from value `0` (`Sunday`) to value `6` (`Saturday`), the implication is that, relative to the given date:

    - For Sunday through Thursday, you'll find the *following* Friday.
    - For Friday, you'll find that day itself.
    - For Saturday, you'll find the *previous* Friday, i.e. the day *before*.
- Generally, as Mathias points out in his answer, you should work with [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) instances while performing date *calculations* and apply *formatting* (conversion to *string* representations) only to the calculation *results*.

  - Note: [`[datetimeoffset]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset) would even be better, due to unambiguously denoting absolute points in time;<sup>[1]</sup> while you can work with this .NET type directly, PowerShell itself unfortunately doesn't offer first-class support for it (yet), such as via [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date); several feature requests are pending as of PowerShell 7.2 - see [this GitHub search](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+datetimeoffset+).

To put it all together:

```sh
# Get today's date without a time-of-day component (via .Date)
# Note: Not strictly necessary, if you use the results only as
#       formatted date-only strings.
$today = (Get-Date).Date

# Find this week's Friday.
$thisFriday = ($today).AddDays(5-($today.DayOfWeek))

# Add an offset.
$futureDate = $thisFriday.AddYears(1)

# Find the future date's adjacent Friday.
$futureFriday = $futureDate.AddDays(5-$futureDate.DayOfWeek)

# Output the result via an aux. object that results in tabular display.
[pscustomobject] @{
  ThisFriday = $thisFriday.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
  FutureFriday = $futureFriday.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
}
```

You'll see output such as the following:

```sh
ThisFriday FutureFriday
---------- ------------
10/08/2021 10/07/2022
```

---

<sup>[1] `[datetimeoffset]` is also *DST*-aware (aware of daylight-saving time) when performing calculations, whereas `[datetime]` appears not to be. This means that even when adding *full* days to `[datetimeoffset]` instances, a calendar-day boundary may be crossed if there is an intervening DST transition.</sup>

Comment: I went with this method.  Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @TechFA; my pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

First add one year:

```
$date = Get-Date 10/08/2021
$date = $date.AddYears(1)
```

Then keep adding one day at a time until you reach a Friday:

```
while($date.DayOfWeek -ne 'Friday'){
  $date = $date.AddDays(1)
}
```

Finally, convert to the desired string format (don't convert to a string until you're done calculating your date, you won't be able to do datetime math with it :) ):

```
$date.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: Ah that was too easy, but I want the Friday before so $date = $date.AddDays(-1)

Comment: Then it won't be 12 months from the date, but sure, you can do whatever you need :-)